# Pop up window on specific time

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to know if there is a way to show scheduled pop up windows, say you're hosting a virtual conference at 6pm, and you want to warn your users an hour early by showing a pop up window at 5pm with a messagge like "Main conference starts in one hour".

This is for a webpage intended to work on desktop and mobile, thus I'm working on HTML and javascript.

Haven't code anything yet, I'm rather looking for a starting point.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: You could have a server send your page/app a push notification.

Comment: @Christian Rodríguez Alvarado, You can use `setInterval` with your own function as parameter which could check the current time and if the current time is xx:xx, then your function would show some custom dialog. Of course, second parameter of the setInterval would be time in milliseconds. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Answer (score 0):

So based on what you just said, I think that the following js code will solve your issue, however, since I don't know what is your current environment, you will have to change the code to your needs:

```js
// Always use a 24 hour format with this implementation.
function scheduleDailyConferences(timeArray) {
    const offset = 60; // alert offset (1h prior in minutes)
    const now = new Date();
    const current = now.getHours() * 60 + now.getMinutes();
    for (let time of timeArray) {
        let tot = time.h * 60 + time.m - offset;
        if (tot < current) continue;
        tot -= current;
        setTimeout(() => {
            alert(`Your meeting starts in ${offset} minutes.`);
        }, tot * 60 * 1000);
    }
}

// assuming the following conferences of the day:
scheduleDailyConferences([
    { h: 13, m: 45 } // 1:45 pm
    { h:  4, m: 00 } // 4:00 pm
]);
```

Basically, given a time table `timeArray` in a human readable format, it reads every entry, subtracts a given offset of 1 hour and figures out when to fire an alert.
If the meeting has already ended or begun, it doesn't fire an alert (but you can easily change that).